# Pathfinding with disappearing platforms - is it solvable?

Tags: logical-deduction, puzzle-creation, visual, reachability

> This is a puzzle but might not have a solution. So "**is it possible?**" is a proper question.
>
> The puzzle idea was inspired by the question [logic problem/puzzle solving](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/7834/logic-problem-puzzle-solving), and if the puzzle here turns out to be solvable, this question would be an *answer* to the linked question. (Hence the cross-link.)

---

Imagine the following situation:

There is a grid of 6x10 rectangular stones of fields of which *some* contain 'magical' stones which are solid under specific circumstances (defined below, shown in grey) and 'vacuum' otherwise. The other fields are 'vacuum' all the time.

> This field is extended by a top and a bottom row of (6) always solid fields (shown in brown on the bottom, omitted on the top.)

There are 6 "players" which want to get across the field. They can only 'walk' on solid fields and (-this is due to the original puzzle question-) along a given path:

[image]

**While a player stands still**, he sends off six straight *rays* defined by the diagonals of the fields and a vertical line. (The centre of the rays is always the centre of the field he's standing in, regardless where on the field the player stands.):

[image]

Now a stone becomes solid (black) if, and only if, **at least two *different* rays cross** over its centre, while rays of a player standing on the platform *do not count*.

> Note that 2 *parallel* rays are not considered *crossing* each other.

So the starting position is:

[image]

Now the puzzle-question is:

> **Can you bring *all* players safely across the field (along the defined path)?**

and if not,

> **Can you bring *at least one* player safely across the field (along the defined path)?**

---

**Notation:**
Assuming only one player moves at a time, you can note its colour and final position (assuming the path to that one is 'walkable'. See my example answer below.

---

### Hints

When *testing* a valid move, do it by the following 3 steps:

> 1. "Remove" a player and his colour and check which platforms are (still) solid.
> 2. Move player along valid, solid path to any position. (Multiple players are allowed on the same field!)
> 3. Add player-rays and check which additional platforms are solid.
> 4. This is the new "next" starting position. Note down the move and restart from 1.

Thanks to [EFrog](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/8858/efrog) there is now also a [helper tool](http://www.fastswf.com/0jk17wE) for checking the situation. (See his answer below for details and instructions.) In accordance to the 4 points above:

> Select a colour (click the big square to change colour) to "pick up" a player. Now check which 'path' is available and move the player to the end-position you want. (The tool does not allow going diagonal directly, but the rules allow it where indicated in the pre-given path.) To set-down a player, simply select another player/colour. Using 'black' mean that all players are set-down.

Comment: Are the starting squares of all the players always solid? What happens to a player who finishes crossing the field? (My best guess would be that they can move freely along a row K, since otherwise the answer to your first question is a trivial "No").

Comment: I haven't heard back from the original poster of that other thread, so I'm making a Flash program to simulate this. (Hopefully.)

Comment: I don't get one thing. If all players stand on same spot, does that spot disappear?

Comment: @shyos, yes. The moment there are less than **two** rays of **different** colour that **cross** (over the *magic* platforms), it disappears. So you always need at least 2 players *not* on the magic platform you want to sustain. (Which reminds me, that I have to draw a "K" line as Peter Taylor suggested. At least if question 1 should get a chance.)

Comment: @BmyGuest thanks. One more question. Do two players' color lines which intersects on everypoint enough to make adjacent platform appear? (i.e. 2 stands on h2; h3,g2,g3 becomes available)

Comment: @shyos No. That is what I meant by *crossing*. (See 2nd step in my example and D5 *not* being solid)

Comment: Well, one could apply standard computational path-finding techniques, like A*, since the states of the game along with the valid moves form a graph (and one can reasonably sum the distances of each player to the top as a heuristic). I'll have to try it to see the graph is a small enough to make this useful.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you can't go from D4 to E4. This does make it harder. Story-wise, perhaps there's an invisible wall between them.

Comment: Also, the platform will disappear when one of the supporting player is moved, even though the movement is parallel to the original ray, isn't it? This problem is indeed tough, haha.

Comment: What differentiates `C2` from `C3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled over this question by chance and it caught my interest.  I am surprised nobody wrote a program to solve it yet.

One question that isn't clear is what happens to a player who is standing on a tile when the tile stops to be solid.  One would expect that the player falls and dies, but that isn't stated explicitly.

Anyway, I wrote a program using its own notation.  I just gave names to the tiles instead of the chess-like notation.  So the board looks like this:

```
V W X Y Z [
. . U . . .
. . . T . .
. Q R S . .
. P O . . .
. . N . . .
. . . M L .
. . . J K .
. . I . . .
. . H . . .
. G . . . .
F E D C B A
```

(Yes, '[' is the 27th letter of the English alphabet!).

I wrote a program to search all possible position accessible from the starting position.  If it is correct, it is not possible to cross the whole path even with a single player.  The furthest anyone can go is square Q.

```
solution: ABCDEF.....................
  C -> H: AB.DEF.H...................
  D -> I: AB..EF.HI..................
  F -> H: AB..E..HI..................
  E -> C: ABC....HI..................
  H -> L: ABC....HI..L...............
  A -> D: .BCD...HI..L...............
  C -> H: .B.D...HI..L...............
  D -> C: .BC....HI..L...............
  H -> K: .BC....HI.KL...............
  B -> D: ..CD...HI.KL...............
  C -> H: ...D...HI.KL...............
  D -> C: ..C....HI.KL...............
  H -> N: ..C....HI.KL.N.............
  C -> D: ...D...HI.KL.N.............
  H -> G: ...D..G.I.KL.N.............
  N -> Q: ...D..G.I.KL....Q..........
  I -> G: ...D..G...KL....Q..........
  D -> G: ......G...KL....Q..........
```

Java source code: https://pastebin.com/kHv7uSEB

If however there are 7 players, 2 players starting on A, then all can cross to the top row.  Here is how.  Each move is displayed with the occupied squares along the path.

```
solution: ABCDEF.....................  
  A -> H: ABCDEF.H...................  
  D -> I: ABC.EF.HI..................  
  F -> L: ABC.E..HI..L...............  
  A -> K: .BC.E..HI.KL...............  
  B -> N: ..C.E..HI.KL.N.............  
  H -> O: ..C.E...I.KL.NO............  
  I -> Q: ..C.E.....KL.NO.Q..........  
  C -> G: ....E.G...KL.NO.Q..........  
  E -> C: ..C...G...KL.NO.Q..........  
  L -> P: ..C...G...K..NOPQ..........  
  C -> B: .B....G...K..NOPQ..........  
  G -> C: .BC.......K..NOPQ..........  
  K -> T: .BC..........NOPQ..T.......  
  B -> D: ..CD.........NOPQ..T.......  
  N -> W: ..CD..........OPQ..T..W....  
  P -> [: ..CD..........O.Q..T..W...[  
  T -> P: ..CD..........OPQ.....W...[  
  W -> Z: ..CD..........OPQ........Z[  
  O -> K: ..CD......K....PQ........Z[  
  C -> G: ...D..G...K....PQ........Z[  
  [ -> Y: ...D..G...K....PQ.......YZ.  
  P -> L: ...D..G...KL....Q.......YZ.  
  Z -> X: ...D..G...KL....Q......XY..  
  D -> P: ......G...KL...PQ......XY..  
  G -> N: ..........KL.N.PQ......XY..  
  Y -> Z: ..........KL.N.PQ......X.Z.  
  P -> O: ..........KL.NO.Q......X.Z.  
  X -> Y: ..........KL.NO.Q.......YZ.  
  L -> P: ..........K..NOPQ.......YZ.  
  K -> S: .............NOPQ.S.....YZ.  
  Z -> [: .............NOPQ.S.....Y.[  
  N -> W: ..............OPQ.S...W.Y.[  
  P -> X: ..............O.Q.S...WXY.[  
  Q -> V: ..............O...S..VWXY.[  
  O -> P: ...............P..S..VWXY.[  
  S -> Z: ...............P.....VWXYZ[  
  P -> V: .....................VWXYZ[
```

Another possibility is to remove the restriction that a stone must remain solid as long as a player stands on it.  If you only need to solidify the stone when stepping on it, the problem becomes possible.

But the original problem taken strictly has no solution.

Comment: Can you post your program here, too?

Comment: It is 200 lines long.

Comment: Thanks for picking this up. You can pastebin your code and just provide the link here, maybe. ? I'm accepting your answer (unless some better comes in the future).

Comment: It is a first for me.  But you learn every day.  I cleaned up the code a bit and pastebin'd it.  The link is in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really an answer, but this is a program that I made that should allow you to better solve this puzzle (or create your own using the same premises).

[BmyGuest's Puzzle](http://fastswf.com/0jk17wE)

**Instructions**

This is a very clunky program that I put together, but it should be fairly user-friendly and easy to work with.

*The grid*: The grid consists of the same 6x10 layout presented in the OP (with one extra row at the bottom to start on and another at top for finishing). Each tile in the grid can be turned "on" or "off" by clicking. Tiles that are turned "on" are indicated by white triangles in the corners, while tiles that are "off" are indicated by black triangles. The tiles that are "on" represent the path -- only these tiles will respond to the characters' positions. (Note that it is set to the default path presented in the OP, but it can be changed if you like.)

*The little arrow things*: In the bottom-right of the screen is a large red box with an arrow on each side. If you click on the red box, it should cycle through the colors (Red > Blue > Green > Yellow > Purple > Orange > Blank/None > Red). Use this to choose which player you intend to control. By clicking on the appropriate arrow button near the selection box, you can then move that character in the indicated direction on the map.

*Other*: You may use the spacebar to place all of the players back in their starting positions. **This does not reset the path to default, just the player positions.**

**Please Note**:

As I said, this is a rather clunky program. So there are a couple of known issues.

First, the player dots are able to move off of the grid. I didn't feel the need to put in restrictions, as this is just a sandbox-style program.

Second, players aren't able to move diagonally in my program; however, this is allowed in the puzzle. Just be sure that you complete each diagonal move you intend and don't stop halfway. :D

I hope this helps and my instructions make sense.

Comment: Finally: I think you could quick-solve the "self collision" by actually not checking the collision of lines, but the collision of lines with the 3 upper OR 3 lower points in each square (left/centre/right). A valid combination has to have 2 or 3 of those points occupied.

Comment: @BmyGuest I updated my post. I actually have it set up to see if a line crosses the very center of the tile. If so, then lineCrosses increases by 1 for every line crossing the center. If lineCrosses is >= 2, then the tile is "solid". That's why when you select a player and turn him hollow, the self-collision doesn't happen (the graphic for the player isn't touching the center of the tile).

Comment: That's nice for the self-collision of the player, but you still have 2 parallel lines (overlaying each other) activating tiles, which by definition shouldn't happen. That's what I meant by the 2 out of 3 condition check as alternative. (You don't need a count for the 3 spots. It doesn't matter how many lines are on it, just that at least 2 spots per tile are "hit" ) Oh, well, yes, and the players on the tile...

Comment: BTW, sorry for being such a P.I.D.A perfectionist. What you've done *is* already great.

Comment: Ah, and you could make up for the mistake I've made in my drawings and add a "solid" line on top. (i.e. shift everything by 1 square downwards, and add a "finish" line on top just like the "starting" line on bottom.) Right now I can already *do* it because I *can* move off-screen, but it's not so nice... ;c)

Comment: @BmyGuest I haven't done any programming in a couple years, and I'm not a pro or anything, so this is actually kinda fun for me. Try this: http://www.fastswf.com/0jk17wE It should handle the parallel lines problem (I have to check five additional points, but it's easy.) as well as including the new finishing line.

Comment: That's it. Perfect tool. It becomes a 'game' if you'd add the 4 diagonals and prevent "invalid" moves of the active player (i.e. moving onto a dark field), but I think for the purpose of testing the puzzle idea, it's already perfect.

Comment: @BmyGuest Updated the post. Feel free to link to it in the OP if you like.

Comment: I think this program counts the player on the tile.  OP specifies that a player does not count for solidity of the tile he is on.

Comment: @Taemyr it shouldn't. The original version did but I've changed it sense then. Do you have a screenshot or example of player coordinates that causes this to happen?

Comment: For example; move blue 3 steps forward and 1 right.  Then green 1 step to the left.  The square that blue is standing on is solid unless orange or blue is the selected player.

Answer (score 2):

> This is a partial answer only, demonstrating the first few (potential) steps.

Each image depicts the situation *after* the named move. Remember *during movement* the *rays* of the moving player are *off*, so all platforms 'held' by his rays (and no other 2 crossing colours) will immediately disappear!

---

**Orange --> A2**

[image: 1=Orange A2]

**Yellow --> C2**

[image: 2=Yellow C2]

**Cyan--> C3**

[image: 3=Cyan C3]

**Orange --> 4**

[image: 4=Orange 4]

**Yellow --> D4**

[image: 5=Yellow D4]

**Purple --> B3**

[image: 6=Purple B3]

*etc...*

Comment: I think if you can get three across while leaving three on the starting row, then you can *nearly* assume that you can get the other three across using just the column lines from the finished three.